# Is it possible for Markov inequality to have at least two points of equality?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, inequality

More formally:
$$\exists? \xi \quad \forall c_1>1, c_2>1 \quad \forall i\in\{1,2\}\ \ P(\xi\geq c_iE\xi)=\frac{1}{c_i}$$